# Express App GET Routing not working in Production Environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running a Node JS server on my Local Host (DEV) and on NameCheap (PROD).

Both environments run the server. Both host the Web Application. The problem I am having is when trying to use the FETCH API in Javascript.

server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var db = require("./db");
var app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || port);

app.route("/queryDB").get(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.query);

  db.query(req.query.query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.send(rows);
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname, { extensions: ["html"] }));
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/css")));
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/js")));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/images")));
app.use("/icons", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/icons")));

app.listen(app.get("port"), "0.0.0.0", () =>
  console.log("Started listening on %s", app.get("port"))
);
```

Function using fetch

```js
export async function queryDB(query) {
  const res = await fetch("../queryDB?query=" + query);
  try {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(res);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I originally had it set up with `app.route` and only using `app.get`. After research started using route.

Tried using `path.join(__dirname + "/queryDB")`

The fetch should return query results from the MySql DB that is set up. Currently I am receiving 
`http://url.com/queryDB?query=SELECT%20Name,%20DATE_FORMAT(Date,%20%22%25W%2C%20%25M%20%25e%2C%20%25Y%22)%20as%20Date,%20Time_Format(Time,%22%25l%3A%25i%20%25p%22)%20as%20Time,%20Description%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20IsRSVP%20=%201%20ORDER%20BY%20Date,%20Time%20ASC`

with the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

In my DEV environment the Query Results in an Array are returned.

EDIT:
When Running `DEBUG=express:* node server` from the name cheap console. I see the routes were created

```
  express:router:route new '/queryDB' +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/queryDB' +0ms
  express:router:route get '/queryDB' +0ms
```

EDIT:

Updated Server.JS

```js
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || port);

app.route("http://url.com/query").all(function(req, res) {
  console.log("Query");
  res.send("Query Res");
  return;
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname, { extensions: ["html"] }));
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/css")));
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/js")));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/images")));
app.use("/icons", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/icons")));

app.listen(app.get("port"), () =>
  console.log("Started listening ons %s", app.get("port"))
);
```

UPdated Function

```
export async function queryDB(query) {
  const res = await fetch("http://url.com/query");

  try {
    if (res.ok) {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(res);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Namecheap probably gives you port 80 so you might have to change your port constant variable to get it from an environment token

Comment: Note that running arbitrary queries from the URL is an apocalyptically awful idea.

Comment: @vortex I am current using an environmental variable for the Port. The Name Cheap port is 8080

Comment: @ZackArnett have you configured the app properly as described in https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10047/2182/how-to-work-with-nodejs-app ?

Comment: @vortex Yes. Thats what I followed to get where I am. The Node Server is running and is hosting the site.

Comment: So GET http://url.com:8080/queryDB?query doesn’t register anything in the namecheap console ? If that’s the case the express app doesn’t listen on the 0.0.0.0 alias

Comment: I have tried with and without the "0.0.0.0" Alias in the `App.Listen` Call. I have simplified the call. So that the fetch call is `fetch("../queryDB")` and the get is just logging to the console and sending back a string. Still Getting `Not found` Error and nothing in the console.

Comment: @vortex ^ Didnt tag..

Comment: I see from your answer that the namecheap console gets the GET. Consequently you made app.route.get(‘queryDB’) rather than app.route.post or .all

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments the fix should be to replace the route you are posting to in your code from `app.route.get` to `app.route.post` if you are using that route to exclusively post or `app.route.all` if you wish both POST and GET functionality.

Comment: The Namecheap Console Output shows the set up of the Route. Changing it to `.all` does not fix this. My Dev environment shows when the Get is made to be   `express:router dispatching GET /db/queryDB +3ms
  express:router query  : /db/queryDB +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /db/queryDB +0ms
`
The production environment doesn't have any output after it starts listening on the port

Comment: Do a return; in between your console.log and db.query but apply the correct changes beforehand: router.all and absolute URIs. That is to stop the execution of a potentially faulty query and ensure your production environment actually listens for the POST http request. You can’t compare your dev environment with the production as they are configured differently

Comment: I have updated the OP. Is this how you are expecting it? Running port 8080 on NameCheap

Comment: No ... you are focusing on semantics rather than the content of my answer/comments

Comment: If you want to succeed stop manipulating the suggestions the whole idea is to debug which part is actually failing. For that you need to contain every possibility and test it individually. Modifying queryDB to query was pointless however you didn’t mention if it works. Does the namecheap console pick your browser requesting /query now ? Server.js looks fixed either way now the question is your client and how you request/post the route.

Comment: Can you post the actual code/method that you use to test server.js ? I see you updated the fetch function however that will never run on namecheap so give some details about your test environment and if you are running it from namecheap... share the transpiled code or the full execution flow. Obviously fix the router again before you do that - it doesn’t understand or have absolute paths so the request will never fulfill

Comment: Another thing I told you to put the empty return right after you console log and before you do anything else to pick it up - you sent the full request and the return void which is opposite to what I tell you to test for. At this point I am confused because I cannot track the changes you make with your actual tests. Again, please share your actual full code for the client/test method not just the server.js

Comment: I apologize for not posting what you were asking for. I have created a new question with the simplest server possible and trying to get that correct before moving on to this issue. It is possible that it has to do with the ports I am using but I can't seem to figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203834/node-js-express-app-app-route-return-404-not-found/56206404#56206404